# Pasting values from different columns and different rows into a new df in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have the following df below:

```
 name name..2 IGD
1 yaaA    recF  16
2 recF    yaaB  18
3 yaaD    yaaE  22
4  dck     dgk  -3
5 dnaX    yaaK  24
6 yaaK    recR  15
7  recR    yaaL  18
8  xpaC    yaaN  19
9  yaaO     tmk  -3
10 yaaQ    yaaR  13
11 yaaR    holB  12
12 holB    yaaT   3
13 yaaT    yabA  15
14 yabB    yazA -13
15 yazA    yabC -25
```

I am trying to find a way to paste together the values from name and name..2 where name..2 matches name in the next row and put that into a new df that should look like this:

```
1 yaaA recF
2 yaaD
3 dck
4 dnaX yaaK recR
5 xpaC
6 yaaO
7 yaaQ yaaR holB yaaT
8 yabB yazA
```

Is there a r function I can use for this? I have tried searching SO, but haven't found a solution yet to this problem. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: So values in column `IGD` can be ignored?

Comment: Yes IGD can be ignored, they are a result of how I put the df together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic is similar to @Wen-Ben here, a `dplyr` way to do this

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group = cumsum(name != lag(name2, default = TRUE))) %>%
  summarise(name = toString(name))

#  group name                  
#  <int> <chr>                 
#1     1 yaaA, recF            
#2     2 yaaD                  
#3     3 dck                   
#4     4 dnaX, yaaK, recR      
#5     5 xpaC                  
#6     6 yaaO                  
#7     7 yaaQ, yaaR, holB, yaaT
#8     8 yabB, yazA
```

The main idea is to create a grouping variable which increments every time `name != name2`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I went with this solution because I already had dplyr loaded in my environment, but all three solutions posted worked on my datasets. The main part I was struggling with was how to increment row by row. I've never had to use that kind of logic before.

Answer (score 2):

In Base R , We using `tail` `head` and `cumsum` create the group key , then using `aggregate`

```
df$id=cumsum(c(TRUE, tail(df$name,-1) != head(df$name2,-1)))

output=aggregate(name ~ id, data = df, toString)
output
  id                   name
1  1             yaaA, recF
2  2                   yaaD
3  3                    dck
4  4       dnaX, yaaK, recR
5  5                   xpaC
6  6                   yaaO
7  7 yaaQ, yaaR, holB, yaaT
8  8             yabB, yazA
```

Comment: The logic is right, but `lag` in this use-case is from dplyr and does not do that in base R (to be precise, `lag` is in the "stats" package included by default, where it is used for timeseries). You could replace it with `cumsum(c(TRUE, tail(df$name,-1) != head(df$name2,-1)))`

Comment: @thelatemail aha thanks for mentioned that, updated

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different option drawing on identifying `clusters` within an `igraph`

```
library(igraph)
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    select(-IGD) %>%
    graph_from_data_frame() %>%
    clusters() %>%
    magrittr::extract2(1) %>%
    split(., .) %>%
    map_dfr(~tibble(x = toString(names(.x)[-length(.x)])))
## A tibble: 8 x 1
#  x
#  <chr>
#1 yaaA, recF
#2 yaaD
#3 dck
#4 dnaX, yaaK, recR
#5 xpaC
#6 yaaO
#7 yaaQ, yaaR, holB, yaaT
#8 yabB, yazA
```

The idea is to construct an `igraph` from `df[c("name", "name..2")]` and then to identify clusters of connected nodes. The clusters are then the groups, and all we need to do is remove the last element (node).

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    " name name..2 IGD
1 yaaA    recF  16
2 recF    yaaB  18
3 yaaD    yaaE  22
4  dck     dgk  -3
5 dnaX    yaaK  24
6 yaaK    recR  15
7  recR    yaaL  18
8  xpaC    yaaN  19
9  yaaO     tmk  -3
10 yaaQ    yaaR  13
11 yaaR    holB  12
12 holB    yaaT   3
13 yaaT    yabA  15
14 yabB    yazA -13
15 yazA    yabC -25", header = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in `data.table` as well

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(name = toString(name)), 
      .(group = cumsum(name != shift(name2, fill = TRUE)))]
#   group                   name
#1:     1             yaaA, recF
#2:     2                   yaaD
#3:     3                    dck
#4:     4       dnaX, yaaK, recR
#5:     5                   xpaC
#6:     6                   yaaO
#7:     7 yaaQ, yaaR, holB, yaaT
#8:     8             yabB, yazA
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("yaaA", "recF", "yaaD", "dck", "dnaX", 
"yaaK", "recR", "xpaC", "yaaO", "yaaQ", "yaaR", "holB", "yaaT", 
"yabB", "yazA"), name2 = c("recF", "yaaB", "yaaE", "dgk", "yaaK", 
"recR", "yaaL", "yaaN", "tmk", "yaaR", "holB", "yaaT", "yabA", 
 "yazA", "yabC"), IGD = c(16L, 18L, 22L, -3L, 24L, 15L, 18L, 19L, 
 -3L, 13L, 12L, 3L, 15L, -13L, -25L)), class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c("1", 
  "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
 "14", "15"))
```